# Prestashop performance - waiting time

Tags: performance, prestashop-1.5

i have a Prestashop installation and the problem is the page is loading very slow.
When i enter any url of my site, the browser is waiting from 2 to 10(!) seconds, and then the site is loading normally. Even if i add product to cart (ajax call), i need to wait few seconds, before cart refresh.

Can someone help me with this?
Here You can see the results of the Pingdom Speed Test:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/d4ktam/minvara.se

As You can see, the site is waiting while languages are loading, but i can't find where the problem is.

Here You can see prestashop debug data:

```
Load time: 9.288s
You'd better run your shop on a toaster
config: 1.376s
constructor: 0ms
init: 4.658s
checkAccess: 0ms
setMedia: 5ms
postProcess: 0ms
initHeader: 0ms
initContent: 3.134s
initFooter: 0ms
display: 114ms
Hook processing: 2.304s / 12.01 Mb
displayRightColumn: 860ms / 1.8 Mb
displayTop: 585ms / 2.73 Mb
moduleRoutes: 290ms / 0.56 Mb
displayLeftColumn: 220ms / 0.64 Mb
displayHeader: 218ms / 5.95 Mb
displayLeftColumnProduct: 120ms / 0.23 Mb
displayMyAccountBlock: 11ms / 0.09 Mb
actionProductOutOfStock: 0ms / 0 Mb
actionDispatcher: 0ms / 0 Mb
displayFooterProduct: 0ms / 0 Mb
actionFrontControllerSetMedia: 0ms / 0 Mb
displayRightColumnProduct: 0ms / 0 Mb
DisplayOverrideTemplate: 0ms / 0 Mb
displayProductButtons: 0ms / 0 Mb
displayProductTab: 0ms / 0 Mb
displayFooter: 0ms / 0 Mb
displayProductTabContent: 0ms / 0 Mb
Memory peak usage: 30.4 Mb
config: 7.15 Mb (7.2 Mb)
constructor: 0 Mb (7.2 Mb)
init: 8.29 Mb (15.6 Mb)
checkAccess: 0 Mb (15.6 Mb)
setMedia: 0.08 Mb (15.7 Mb)
postProcess: 0 Mb (15.7 Mb)
initHeader: 0.01 Mb (15.7 Mb)
initContent: 12.43 Mb (28.2 Mb)
initFooter: 0.01 Mb (28.2 Mb)
display: 1.36 Mb (30.4 Mb)


Total cache size (in Cache class): 0 Mb
DB type: DbPDO 
SQL Queries: 129 queries 
Time spent querying: 8.532s
Included files: 218
Size of included files: 2.66 Mb
Globals (> 1 Ko only): 830 Ko
_MODULES ≈ 401.5 Ko
_LANG ≈ 313 Ko
_SERVER ≈ 18.7 Ko
HTTP_SERVER_VARS ≈ 18.6 Ko
_ENV ≈ 18.1 Ko
HTTP_ENV_VARS ≈ 18.1 Ko
smarty ≈ 12.6 Ko
context ≈ 12.6 Ko
_COOKIE ≈ 3 Ko
HTTP_COOKIE_VARS ≈ 3 Ko
_MODULE ≈ 1.5 Ko
_transient ≈ 1.5 Ko
_GET ≈ 1.4 Ko
```

Comment: it looks like the redirect to /en folder is taking up most of the time. Did you try stopping the redirect?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: How do you get this debug data?